# Jest Reference Error when testing 2 functions

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, jestjs

I am writing jest test for a function A that uses another function B.

```
function A(str) {
  let count = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) if (B(str[i])) ++count;

  return count;
}
```

This is function that A is using

```
function B(ch) {
  ch = ch.toUpperCase();

  return ch == "A" || ch == "B" || ch == "X" || ch == "Y" || ch == "Z";
}
```

This is the jest test:

```
const A = require("./A");
const B = require("./B");

test("Test A using B", () => {
  const ch = A("ABC");
  expect(ch).toBe(1);
});
```

It gives error: ReferenceError: B is not defined. How to resolve it?

Comment: I think you missing  import B in A

Comment: It's nothing to do with Jest, that's just the thing that's telling you your _actual implementation_ doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks , i added module.imports = B; and it workd.

Comment: In your file where you implemented A you have to import B.